# Hide second line of text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a line of code:

```
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

How can I hide the line of text after the line break `<br>` with CSS?

Comment: Too bad we cannot do `br::after { content : "␡␡␡␡␡␡" }`

Comment: @mplungjan You can do, but it would not have an effect, because pseudo-elements like `::after` and `::before` are not appended *after* the element, but at the end *inside* the element. `br` is an element without content and therefore cannot have pseudo elements (like `img`). But event if it would be, it won't work the way you intend.

Comment: I know, it was just for fun. ::after as you say does not work on content-less elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't target text nodes in CSS like you can in JavaScript, so it would be impossible to hide the text after the `<br>` with your current markup.

You need to modify it to wrap the part of the text you want to hide in a separate element. For example:

```
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br><span style="display: none">Jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>
```

### **Using CSS**

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br><span>Jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.site-info span{display: none}
```

Comment: Adding to @cjl750 answer - instead of using inline css i will prefer to use external css.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `height` relative the font-size (The same as the `line-height` value) and the set `overflow: hidden`

```css
.site-info {
    border: solid 2px blue;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `overflow: hidden` and a height equal to the line-height.

```
.site-info {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is not the best solution, but you dont need to wrap the part you want to hide

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake here is a JS version

NOTE that removing nodes from the div from the beginning will alter the sequence - if we remove the BR in a loop, the two textnodes will merge so we need to do it backwards

```js
var si = document.querySelector(".site-info")
var nodes = si.childNodes;
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className="hide"
for (var i=nodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  var n = nodes[i];
  console.log(n.tagName || n.wholeText)
  span.insertBefore(n,span.firstChild)
  if (n.tagName=="BR") break;
};
si.appendChild(span)
```

```css
.hide { color:red }/* display: none }*/
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```