# Nodes disappear from loop when appended

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

[Simplest Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522299/295783)

I am trying to answer [Hide second line of text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519441/hide-second-line-of-text-with-css) with a JS version

Why does the second line disappear **from my loop**? Is the textnode stuck to the BR for some reason?

I want to hide the BR and subsequent lines but I do not move the second line to the span

Expected result is when BR is encountered, it and all following nodes are moved to the span and at the end the span is appended to the div where the br used to be, making the second line red in this case

I played with cloneNode which worked better but I wanted to move the nodes, not clone them. I also thought about substring the innerHTML but was worried that the various rendering and toString of BR is not reliable

Input:

`<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>`

Expected output:

`<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <span class="hide"><br>Jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>`

Attempt:

```js
var si = document.querySelector(".site-info")
var nodes = si.childNodes;
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className="hide"
var found = false;
nodes.forEach(n => {
  console.log(n.tagName || "No tag",n.wholeText || "No text")
  if (n.tagName==="BR") { // first br found
    found = true; 
  }  
  if (found) { // from now on to end of all nodes
    span.appendChild(n) // n.cloneNode(true) 
  }
});
si.appendChild(span)
```

```css
.hide { color:red }/* display: none }*/
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

---

Expected result NOTE: color:red will be display:none in real version, resulting in the second line appearing WITH the BR if display:none is removed by code

```css
.hide { color:red }
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <span class="hide"><br>Jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>
```

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a `console.log(nodes)` before the the loop you will notice that the span is already included as a childNode.

[image]

That seems to mess with the logic of `span.appendChild` while looping through the nodes.

Edit: As per the comments, when calling `appendChild` for the `br` tag, the elements gets removed from the DOM which alteres the reference inside the `nodes` array and causes the two text nodes to combine as they are not seperated anymore. So the loop will not reach the former 3rd iteration anymore as that array element does not exist anymore.

If you pull the logic for appending the nodes outside the loop it works:

```js
var si = document.querySelector(".site-info")
var nodes = si.childNodes;
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "hide"
var found = false;
let childs = [];
nodes.forEach((n, i) => {
  if (n.tagName === "BR") {
    found = true;
  }
  if (found) {
    childs.push(n);
  }
});
if (childs.length > 0) {
  childs.forEach((n) => {
    span.appendChild(n);
  });
  si.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

That being said I actually haven't found a reason for that happening so there might be a more elegant solution to that.

Comment: I think what's happening is that once the `br` is removed, `childNodes[0] = A quick brown fox` and `childNodes[2] = Jumps over the lazy dog` combines into one childNode, hence, a 3rd iteration never happens. Such that the span only contains the `<br>` element

Comment: But why would that happen? We don't touch the `nodes` variable unless `appendChild` has a reference to the elements inside that variable and alters the array dynamically. And that still does not explain why the `span` already exists at the start of the script befpre being appended to `si`

Comment: Thanks for confirming I am not crazy - I contemplated pushing them to an array (hence the cloneNode comment - but that does not remove them from the div as I wanted

Comment: @empiric, once you append the `br` to the in-memory `span` (which is not yet appended in the DOM in this case), the rendered `br` is removed from the DOM nonetheless. Hence, once removed, the childNodes combine into one. You can simulate this by logging the length of the `nodes` before and during the loop. You'd see it turns from `3` to `2`

Comment: @AbanaClara now I get what you are saying, but that would mean js is altering a reference inside my variable at runtime (if I phrased that correctly). So for the original script to work I would need to clone the child nodes, iterate over them and append from the original nodes, does that make sense?

Comment: @empiric Exactly. For the original script to work, we somehow need to create a new array that won't get messed up like the original NodeList which is directly referencing the DOM element. Then we empty the original element and insert a new set of nodes iinm

Comment: So I simply have to start from the end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522299/295783

Comment: @mplungjan reversing the loop is actually pretty clever haha. Didn't think of that

Answer (score 3):

We already have an accepted answer working around the problem. But we found out that the real issue is the removal of the `br` element during the iteration messes with the original childNodes array.

Originally it is

```
<div>
A quick brown fox
<br>
Jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
```

which is divided into `3` nodes.

During the original code, which removes the `br` element and inserts it to a new span. What happens is that the two separate childNodes combine into one.

```
<div>
A quick brown fox

<!-- <br> is removed -->

Jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
```

Such that a 3rd iteration never happens, since the length of the nodes goes from `3` to `2`

The resulting HTML becomes

```
<div>
A quick brown fox
Jumps over the lazy dog
<span><br/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to - when br is encountered, the br and subsequent nodes are moved to the span. I then assumed that appending the span to the div, would result in `<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>`

Comment: You realise that appending br to the span basically makes the breakpoint invisible in this case? Since it is wrapped inside the span.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. When display:none instead of color:red is used and is removed, then the hidden content is shown on a new line

Comment: @mplungjan No. If you insert both the br and subsequent nodes inside the span and make it `display: none`, you won't see anything else but the first line....

Comment: Please read my updated question. I see I was not being clear that the secodn line disappears from my LOOP

Comment: So the issue is the removal of the BR alters the div child nodes

Comment: @mplungjan I believe so. The removal of the BR messes with the iteration

Comment: Embarassingly I should have known the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522299/295783 earlier

Answer (score 3):

Since we cannot move from the beginning, we can in this case move from the end

```js
var si = document.querySelector(".site-info")
var nodes = si.childNodes;
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className="hide"
for (var i=nodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  var n = nodes[i];
  console.log(n.tagName || n.wholeText)
  span.insertBefore(n,span.firstChild)
  if (n.tagName=="BR") break;
};
si.appendChild(span)
```

```css
.hide { color:red }/* display: none }*/
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time `appendChild` is being called, the element is *moved* to the `span`, that changes the `nodes`'s size. Instead we could make a deep clone of all nodes ans maintain a variable `c` to keep in check how many nodes to skip as `nodesCopy` will vary with loop and `nodes` won't:

```js
var si = document.querySelector(".site-info")
var nodes = [];
var nodesCopy = si.childNodes;
si.childNodes.forEach(element => nodes.push(element.cloneNode(true)));
var c = 0;
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "hide"
var found = false;
console.log(nodes.length);
nodes.forEach((n, i) => {
  console.log(n.tagName || "No tag", n.wholeText || "No text");
  if (n.tagName === "BR") {
    found = true;
  }
  if (found) {
    c++;
    si.removeChild(nodesCopy[i - c + 1]);
    span.appendChild(n);
  }
});
console.log(nodes.length);
si.appendChild(span);
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red
}


/* display: none }*/
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

Comment: Yeah - as you can see on my original code, I was thinking of cloning too, but was annoyed that I then also had to modify the div instead of having the nodes removed while moving

Comment: @mplungjan agreed, very tedious

Comment: Solution: do it from the end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522299/295783 - I even knew this trick from elsewhere :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code seems to be doing exactly what you tell it to do. In this case: Loop over all the childnodes, if a `<br>` is found append it to the newly created `<span>` and add the `<span>` to the `.site-info` div.

And so your output becomes this:

```
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox Jumps over the lazy dog<span class="hide"><br></span></div>
```

**Edit:** You could take a different approach by checking the string for occurrences of the `<br>` tag, cut the string and paste the selection into a literal string like so:

```js
var si = document.querySelector(".site-info");
var html = si.innerHTML;
var index = html.indexOf('<br>');
var selection = html.slice(index, html.length);
si.innerHTML = html.substring(0, index) + '<span class="hide">' + selection + '</span>';

// Log the output
console.log(si.innerHTML);
```

```css
.hide { color:red }/* display: none }*/
```

```html
<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

This does need some validation though, but does do what you are looking for.

Comment: I am not supposed to STOP the loop. I want to append br and all subsequent nodes to the span and then append the span to the div, resulting in `<div class="site-info">The quick brown fox <br>Jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>`

Comment: So your answer is correct,  - what I missed seeing is that when the BR is removed, the two text nodes combine

Comment: I've added a different approach for you to look at.

Comment: I tried that, however I found it VERY dangerous since the representation of the br differed from rendered and string (<br></br> in toString, BR as tagName etc)

Comment: Agreed, empiric has the more formidable solution in your case.

Comment: I am a little embarrassed - the solution was to move from end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522299/295783